# Reference request: The area of the modular curve $\mathcal{H}/SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is $\pi/3$.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm looking for a reference that the hyperbolic area of the modular curve $\mathcal{H}/SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is $\pi/3$.

Also, what is the measure relative to which this is true? In what sense is this measure "canonical"? (ie, why do we choose this measure, and not, say, 5 times this measure?)

Comment: For your first question: if you know the usual fundamental domain of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, the area can be computed as an integral over this domain, as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30502/hyperbolic-area-and-sl-2).

Comment: It's the area associated to the canonical hyperbolic metric; the conformal metric that gives the curve Gaussian curvature $-1$.